# How do install Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, installation

The help has a load of different options. I tried:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

which returns:

```
      [RuntimeException]
  Not enough arguments.
```

And then there is a load of articles referencing the windows installer located at:

http://laravel.com/laravel.phar

Which says:
"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

I'm not sure what else to try? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This should have worked, maybe the tilde needs escaping on your shell (`\~`), or you could try one of the other formats accepted by the command :

```
Usage:
 require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [packages1] ... [packagesN]

Arguments:
 packages                    Required package with a version constraint, e.g. foo/bar:1.0.0 or foo/bar=1.0.0 or "foo/bar 1.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here u can see the installation instructions:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation

It comes down to this:

1. Install composer
2. Download laravel
3. Put it in the www folder of wamp so you have www/laravel-master
4. Right click in the root of laravel-master and select composer install
5. Ready to go

I assumed u use WAMP, if u use something else, put laravel in the map where all your projects are located.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MAMP`, this `youtube` [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2jUTeiymY4) will help. It did help me, although I admit in the end it's not as clear as I want it to be.

Anyways, I made my own notes just in case i have to do it again.

a. add `MAMP`'s `PHP` to PATH VARIABLE in .bash_profile

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin:$PATH
```

maybe not necessary step if you have an updated `php` with `mcrypt`, I just chose to use `MAMP`'s `php`

b. install `Composer`
go to http://www.getcomposer.org/ ->getting started ->globally copy and execute 2 commands, 
at the terminal…

```
cd ~
curl -sS https:/?getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

c. install `Laravel` at `MAMP/htdocs` folder using `composer`,
at the terminal…

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
composer create-project laravel/laravel neji --prefer-dist
```

******where neji is the name of your website/project

d. edit  `/private/etc/hosts`

```
sudo nano /private/etc/hosts
add 127.0.0.1 neji
```

e. using any textEditor edit `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`
uncomment by removing the `#` before include… on the virtual hosts, see below where...

```
 # Virtual Hosts
 #Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

becomes...

```
 # Virtual Hosts
 Include  /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

f. using any textEditor edit `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
add the following text at the bottom

```
# I am not sure about this since DocumentRoot does not points to the public folder
# but I still added it and it's working, maybe someone will clarify this part
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.localhost
#     ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
#     CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

# this one, I think is the code that makes it work bec the DocumentRoot points to public folder
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin neji.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/neji/public/"
    ServerName neji.dev
    ServerAlias www.neji
#     ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
#     CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

** **2 things to note**
1. set ServerName to your projectName(neji.dev) 
2. set DocumentRoot to the public folder

g. open your project using your fav browser

```
neji.dev/
```

******don’t forget the `/` at the end

You should see the `laravel` welcome page.

Then after a few days switch to `VM` :)

Comment: sorry dude I just realized you are using windows